# API can't return respone after run shell_exec Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shell, api, exec

I'm trying to exec a shell file when user calling my API. This is my code wrote in Laravel **routes/api.php**:

```
    Route::get('process', function() {
         define("SHELL_PATH","/home/ubuntu");
         ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);

         $arrProcess = array(
             "sudo sh",
             "./shell.sh",
             "NAME=taanh",
             "2>&1"
         );

         chdir(SHELL_PATH);
         $process = shell_exec(implode(" ", $arrProcess));
         return response()->json([
             "status" => 0,
             "process" => $process
         ],200);
    });
```

My **shell.sh** take about 30s to execute so i set **max_execution_time** to **60**. I've try to set it up to **300**.

The shell run successfully but api return **The connection was reset** instead of my json response.

I also try **Symfony/Process** but still face this problem.

```
define("SHELL_PATH","/home/ubuntu");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);

$arrProcess = array(
    "sudo sh",
    "./shell.sh",
    "NAME=taanh",
    "2>&1"
);

chdir(SHELL_PATH);
$process = new Process(implode(" ", $arrProcess));
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => 1,
            "code" => 5004,
            "msg" => "Error when run site",
        ],500);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => 0,
            "msg" => "Run shell successfully",
            "process" => $buffer
        ],200);
    }
});
```

Any problem in my code? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Solved!**

In my **shell.sh** include a line that make nginx restart. Edit my sh file fix the problem.